# Blacklist DOM elements with Mutation Observers

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome, mutation-observers

I would like to use Mutation Observers in Chrome to monitor DOM changes in the entire document. However, I would like to blacklist specific elements with certain `id`'s. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Use mutation-summary library found here: http://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/ . The element query summarizes the changes to the presence and location of elements matching the given selector string. found here: http://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/wiki/APIReference#The_element_Query